# How to compress a .net object instance using gzip

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching, compression

I am wanting to compress results from QUERYS of the database before adding them to the cache.

I want to be able to compress any reference type.

I have a working version of this for compressing strings.. the idea based on scott hanselman 's blog post http://shrinkster.com/173t

any ideas for compressing a .net object?

I know that it will be a read only cache since the objects in the cache will just be byte arrays..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This won't work for **any** reference type. This will work for **Serializable** types. Hook up a `BinaryFormatter` to a compression stream which is piped to a file:

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var outputFile = new FileStream("OutputFile", FileMode.CreateNew))
using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(
                         outputFile, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
   formatter.Serialize(compressionStream, objToSerialize);
   compressionStream.Flush();
}
```

You could use a `MemoryStream` to hold the contents in memory, rather than writing to a file. I doubt this is really an effective solution for a cache, however.

Comment: thank you this has been really helpful, what would the decompress look like... never used BinaryFormatter before.

Comment: Thanks for making this easily copy+pastable into my code.  I format things often enough that this is now just a snippet I can easily find on Google.  +1

Answer (score 3):

What sort of objects are you putting in the cache? Are they typed objects? Or things like `DataTable`? For `DataTable`, then perhaps store as xml compressed through `GZipStream`. For typed (entity) objects, you'll probably need to serialize them.

You could use `BinaryFormatter` and `GZipStream`, or you could just use something like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) serialization (free) which is already very compact (adding `GZipStream` typically makes the data *larger* - which is typical of dense binary). In particular, the advantage of things like protobuf-net is that you get the reduced size without having to pay the CPU cost of unzipping it during deserialization. In [some tests](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) *before* adding `GZipStream`, it was 4 times faster than `BinaryFormatter`. Add the extra time onto `BinaryFormatter` for GZip and it should win by a *considerable* margin.

Answer (score 3):

I just added GZipStream support for my app today, so I can share some code here;

Serialization:

```
using (Stream s = File.Create(PathName))
{
    RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
    rm.Key = CryptoKey;
    rm.IV = CryptoIV;
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(s, rm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (GZipStream gs = new GZipStream(cs, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(gs, _instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(PathName))
{
    RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
    rm.Key = CryptoKey;
    rm.IV = CryptoIV;
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(s, rm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        using (GZipStream gs = new GZipStream(cs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            _instance = (Storage)bf.Deserialize(gs);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: if you use CryptoStream, it is kinda important that you chain (un)zipping and (de)crypting right this way, because you'll want to lose your entropy BEFORE encryption creates noise from your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how this can be done.

**GzipStream**: Provides methods and properties used to compress and decompress streams.

Serialize object to Memory stream using binaryformatter and hook that memorystream to Gzipstream.

Code to compress is as follows:

```
            public static byte[] ObjectToCompressedByteArray(object obj)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                            {
                                using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                                {
                                    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                                    binaryFormatter.Serialize(gZipStream, obj);
                                }
                                return memoryStream.ToArray();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            LoggerWrapper.CMLogger.LogMessage(
                                $"EXCEPTION: BSExportImportHelper.ObjectToByteArray - : {ex.Message}", LoggerWrapper.CMLogger.CMLogLevel.Error);
                            throw;
                        }

                    }
```