# BinaryFormatter & CryptoStream problem when deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, encryption-symmetric

I'm getting a bit desperate here. I'm trying to write an encrypted file with a serialized object to disk and later retrieve the file, decrypt it and deserialize the object back.

UPDATE:
I refactored the code to this:

```
using (Stream innerStream = File.Create(this.GetFullFileNameForUser(securityContext.User, applicationName)))
            {
                using (Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(innerStream, GetCryptoProvider().CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // 3. write to the cryptoStream 
                    //BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    //bf.Serialize(cryptoStream, securityContext);
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SecurityContextDTO));
                    xs.Serialize(cryptoStream, securityContext);
                }
            }


 using (Stream innerStream = File.Open(this.GetFullFileNameForUser(user, applicationName), FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (Stream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(innerStream, GetCryptoProvider().CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                //BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                //return (SecurityContextDTO)bf.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SecurityContextDTO));
                //CryptographicException here
                return (SecurityContextDTO)xs.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
            }
        }
```

Now I'm getting a cryptographic exception on deserialize: Bad Data

ORIGINAL:

I'm doing this:

```
public void StoreToFile(SecurityContextDTO securityContext, string applicationName)
    {
        if (securityContext.LoginResult.IsOfflineMode == false)
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            CryptoStream crStream = null;
            try
            {
                TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = GetCryptoProvider();

                stream = File.Open(this.GetFullFileNameForUser(securityContext.User, applicationName), FileMode.Create);
                crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
                   cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                bFormatter.Serialize(crStream, securityContext);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (crStream != null)
                    crStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }



public SecurityContextDTO RetrieveFromFile(UserDTO user,string applicationName)
    {
        SecurityContextDTO objectToSerialize;
        Stream stream = null;
        CryptoStream crStream=null;
        try
        {
            stream = File.Open(this.GetFullFileNameForUser(user, applicationName), FileMode.Open);
             crStream= new CryptoStream(stream,
                GetCryptoProvider().CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            //Exception here
            objectToSerialize = (SecurityContextDTO)bFormatter.Deserialize(crStream); 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            objectToSerialize = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (crStream!=null)
                crStream.Close();
        }
        return objectToSerialize;
    }


private static TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider GetCryptoProvider()
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        try
        {
            cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CrypKey);

            Rfc2898DeriveBytes db = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("sdddsdsd", 8);
            cryptic.IV = db.GetBytes(8);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            cryptic.Dispose();
        }
        return cryptic;
    }
```

Encrypting and writing works fine, the file appears on the disk and the content is there (encrypted of course). But when I call the retrieve method I always get a SerializationException

> Binary stream '30' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.

When I leave the cryptographic methods out everything works fine.

Comment: You should use `using` statements.

Comment: There are two possibilities here - the exception points to the latter, however, the other possibility is that your encryption code is corrupting the data (or simple file corruption has occurred). Have you previously successfully saved and reloaded this data? Re the "object version changes" - I cannot stress enough (and do, almost daily) that `BinaryFormatter` is usually a bad choice if you want to *store* data - it is OK for *transport*, but not for persistence. The problem is: it is **very** flakey with versioning. There are alternative serializers that are more suitable for future usage.

Comment: Refactoring to using statements didnt help, without the crypto stuff, storing & reloading the object works fine but I never managed to load the encrypted data this way...

Comment: I updated the post to reflect my code changes.

Comment: 100 perecent certain you're not configuring/ creating your encryptor\decryptor correctly. I Really suggest you start by manualy creating them, and using them directly, to encrypt/ decrypt some byte arrays in memory. And also that try using AES and familiarize yourself with its parameters. after that the various .Net shortcuts become easy.

Comment: Can you provide any links for creating encryptors manually? Am I doing something wrong in the GetCryptoProvider() method?

Comment: What is the variable `user` you use in your second call the `this.GetFullFileNameForUser`? Can I assume you are reading the same file you saved?

Comment: Yes it is the same file, if i leave the crypto stuff out, everything stores and loads just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

You realize that in this code

```
private static TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider GetCryptoProvider()
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    try
    {
        cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CrypKey);

        Rfc2898DeriveBytes db = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("sdddsdsd", 8);
        cryptic.IV = db.GetBytes(8);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        cryptic.Dispose(); // <------- Don't do this until you are done decrypting.
    }
    return cryptic;
}
```

you will ALWAYS dispose of the provider meaning you are always using a random key and iv

Comment: D'oh! *banging my head against the table* Thank you and all the others that made me smarter :)

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  However, the stream you pass into the creation of CryptoStream is *always, always, always* the  buffer that will hold your end result.  It is *not* the stream that holds the data you want to encrypt or decrypt.  I put the emphasis in there because I remember learning this for the first time and I did exactly what you were doing.  So here:

```
// this is for encryption
var memStreamEncryptedData = new MemoryStream();
var encryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStreamEncryptedData, 
   transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

// this is for decryption
var memStreamDecryptedData = new MemoryStream();
var decryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStreamDecryptedData, 
   transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

Notice in both cases, CryptoStream is being initialized with a blank output stream.  Your stream does not enter into the picture until later.  So, during a write, you will do the following:

```
encryptStream.Write(dataToBeEncrypted);
encryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
encryptStream.Close();
// memStreamEncryptedData now safely holds your encrypted data
```

And during the read, you will:

```
decryptStream.Write(dataToBeDecrypted);
encryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
encryptStream.Close();
// memStreamDecryptedData now safely holds your decrypted data
```

So, to save you some trouble, here's a nice simple Symmetric method that will perform both encryption and decryption.  The only difference between this and yours is that I am working directly on byte arrays, but perhaps that augmentation can be an exercise:

```
public static byte[] Symmetric(bool encrypt, byte[] plaintext, string ikey)
{
    if (plaintext.Length == 0) return plaintext;

    // setting up the services can be very expensive, so I'll cache them
    // into a static dictionary.
    SymmetricSetup setup;
    if (!_dictSymmetricSetup.TryGetValue(ikey, out setup))
    {
        setup = new SymmetricSetup();
        setup.des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, 
            Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
        setup.hash = Hash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ikey));
        setup.key = setup.hash.ForceLength(8, 0);
        setup.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("init vec");
        setup.des.Key = setup.key;
        setup.des.IV = setup.IV;

        setup.encrypt = setup.des.CreateEncryptor(setup.des.Key, setup.des.IV);
        setup.decrypt = setup.des.CreateDecryptor(setup.des.Key, setup.des.IV);
        _dictSymmetricSetup[ikey] = setup;
    }

    var transform = encrypt ? setup.encrypt : setup.decrypt;

    var memStreamEncryptedData = new MemoryStream();

    var encStream = new CryptoStream(memStreamEncryptedData, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    if (encrypt)
        encStream.Write(new[] {(byte) ((8 - (plaintext.Length + 1)%8)%8)}, 0, 1);

    encStream.Write(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length);
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    encStream.Close();

    memStreamEncryptedData.Flush();

    var ciphertext = memStreamEncryptedData.ToArray();

    byte b;

    if (!encrypt)
        if (byte.TryParse("" + ciphertext[0], out b))
            ciphertext = ciphertext.Skip(1).Take(ciphertext.Length - b - 1).ToArray();

    return ciphertext;
}
```

And to call it, you might do something like this:

```
static public byte[] DecryptData(this byte[] source, string password) {
    return Symmetric(false, source, password);
}

static public byte[] EncryptData(this byte[] source, string password) {
    return Symmetric(true, source, password);
}
```

Again, you'll do something slightly different to work with streams, but hopefully you get the gist.  Instead of MemoryStream, it will be whatever stream you need to feed into your serializer.

Comment: One comment -- In the example, I use DES instead of TripleDes.  You will want to use TripleDES or AES.  Your FIPS compliance audit will thank you.  :-)

Comment: Ok, second comment -- my implementation has a little something extra.  I encode a byte at the beginning of my encryption stream to tell me how many padding bytes were added at the end of the encrypted string.  The problem with block ciphers is that they do, in fact, operate a block at a time, and you need to come up with some way to strip this out.

Comment: I've been informed that the solution for your case is much simpler.  In our application, I was encoding random arrays of data using block mode.  :-)  Thanks, Andrew.  Hopefully what he wrote works.

Answer (score 0):

Some previous posts that can be of use:

[How do I encrypt a string in vb.net using RijndaelManaged, and using PKCS5 padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962900/how-do-i-encrypt-a-string-in-vb-net-using-rijndaelmanaged-and-using-pkcs5-paddin/3962945#3962945)

[Does BinaryFormatter apply any compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341843/does-binaryformatter-apply-any-compression/5950845#5950845)

In later, you can see how I stacked compression with encryption with serialization.  And it works.